# access and change parent page from iframe (with jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

is there any way how to access from iframe to parrent page (and change parrent page)?

```
<body>
   <iframe src="frame1.html" name="frame1" height="100%"></iframe>
   <div id="test1"></div>
</body>
```

In frame1.html is `<a href=..>` and I want to add text "`<h1>clicked</h1>`" into `<div id="test1"></div>`, when the `<a href..>` was clicked.

Thanks.

Comment: For many security reasons this is not possible.

Comment: @ChristianVarga not entirely true: It's allowed across elements residing in the same domain.

Answer (score 25):

If your child page (frame1.html) is located at the same domain as the parent page, You can write a code like below in the child window :

```
 $('#test1', parent.document).html('<h1>clicked</h1>');
```

The second parameter provides the `context` in which to search the element matched by the first parameter. The Document is here:http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context

```
 jQuery( selector [, context ] )
```

So, your code (frame1.html) could go like this:

```
 <a href="..." 
  onclick="$('#test1', parent.document).html('<h1>clicked</h1>');">click me</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

**Important note:** Accessing in and out iframes is only possible, if both, parent and iframe are from the same domain, else you have no access due to *Same Origin Policy*.

Note, that both parts have their own document. Accessing the parent object from iframe is simple with

```
parent.document
```

and from parent it is one of the following:

```
window.frames['iframeName']

(window.frames.length /*gives you the number of iframes in your document*/ )
```

or reference it with id and do the following (watch out for support!)

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
var doc = iframe.contentDocument? iframe.contentDocument:iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

Answer (score 4):

The code below should work fine:

```
$(parent.document).find("#selector");
```

The selector is from the parent document to perform some action. For Example:

```
$(parent.document).find("#selector").remove();
```