# Can the iframe content changes the "title" page?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, aruba

I have an hosting service with a masking redirect service.

example

I have this domain: www.the_domain_whith_redirect.com

and redirect page: http://www.the_real_path.com/index.html

In the address bar of my browser I read "www.the_domain_whith_redirect.com" but I view the "http://www.the_real_path.com/index.html" content

---

reading the source of the page, the masking works like this

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>www.the_domain_whith_redirect.com</title>
    </head>

    <frameset framespacing="0" border="0" rows="0,*" frameborder="0">
      <frame name="topmask" src="mask.htm" scrolling="no" noresize>
      <frame name="bottommask" src="http://www.the_real_path.com/index.html" scrolling="auto">
    </frameset>

    </html>
```

I can't modify this 'cause I have no physical access to the "www.the_domain_whith_redirect.com" domain. It's only a domain.
I can modify, through control panel of my provider (Aruba.it), the redirect link, that is the real physical page.

---

**Now. The Question is:**

Can I modify the title of the "Master" page 
(in this example: www.the_domain_whith_redirect.com), 
through Javascript or through other way, from the iframe content?

This because the Browser, in the **title bar** show me "www.the_domain_whith_redirect.com" and not "Hello, this is the real title of my physical site"

---

Thanks for answers

Oscar

Comment: I know you could do this if the pages were on the same domain. I'm afraid you are going to bump into the same origin access restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can't change the property directly, but you can call a function on the parent page to set the parent page's title.

> If your child page (frame1.html) is located at same domain as parent
>   page, and if it is allowed to write a javascript code in the
>   frame1.html, You can call a parent window's function from frame1.html.
>
> In the child page (frame1.html) :
>
> ```
> <a href="..." onclick="parent.callFromChildPage()">text</a>
> ```
>
> And, In the parent page :
>
> ```
> <script language="javascript">
> function callFromChildPage(){
>     $("#test1").html("<h1>clicked</h1>");
> }
> </script>
> ```
>
> And also, if you can use jQuery in the child page (frame1.html), you
>   can set　parent page's element directly as follows:
>
> ```
> <a href="..." onclick="$('#test1', window.parent.document).html('<h1>clicked</h1>');">text</a>
> ```

Source: [access and change parent page from iframe (with jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748449/access-and-change-parent-page-from-iframe-with-jquery)

Comment: Ok, but this is possible if I can modify the parent page. But in this case, I can't.