# Changing the innerhtml on another page does not work in Chrome (they are in the same domain)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, parent, innerhtml

I have build a website with an iframe to display multiple subpages.
My goal is to change the value of an ID on the parent window, from the child page that is loaded in the Iframe. All the pages are in the same domain. I am currently using the following code, and it works fine in Internet explorer, but doesn't do anything in Chrome? I hope someone will have the awnser to fix it so it will work in all browsers.
Thank you in advance!

Here's the html of the parent window:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Webpage</title>
  <base target="iframe">

  <!-- External Javascript -->
  <script src="javascript/index.js"></script>

  <!-- External CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Banner -->
  <div class="Banner">

    <div id="Site-name">
      Text to be changed
    </div>
    <img class="Logo" src="Afbeeldingen/Logo.png" alt="logo">

  </div>

  <!-- Body -->

  <div class="iframe">
    <iframe name="iframe" src="iframe.html"></iframe>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="Footer">
    <div class="copyright">
      Made by Jan Pieter van den Oever 2019 All rights reserved ®
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And here is the java script of the index file:

```
function changeText(text) {
  document.getElementById('Site-name').innerHTML = text;
}
```

Here is the iframe html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>iframe</title>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iframe.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="Button-container">
    <div class="Button-center">
      <div class="Button" onclick="location.href='nextpage.html';parent.changeText('The new text to be displayed in the parent')">
        <div class="Button-text">
          <br><br><br>
          Start
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try this solution - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748449/access-and-change-parent-page-from-iframe-with-jquery)

Comment: Thanks akshithDayanand but thats in Jquiry, i don't understand it good enough to implement it right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
function changeText(newText) {

$('#Site-name').text(newText)

}
```

Just include jQuery in your project and replace the changeText function with the above one. If the above code doesn't work, try the below one:

```
function changeText(newText) {

$(document).find('#Site-name').text(newText);

}
```

Comment: Where do i have to state this jQuery? In the parent or iframe project?

Comment: try placing it in the parent

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work... Thanks for helping me btw.

Comment: No. But when i use the chrome debugger i see the following:

**Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick**

So how to fix this? They are in the same domain so it must be posible...

Comment: @Jpvdo, Oh, that means chrome is blocking your page from accessing the local html file inside iFrame. CORS issue to be exact. One solution is to upload your files to a web server and try running the code. or you can install a local web server like wamp or xampp and try running your project inside that.

Answer (score 0):

It's so confusing, so you are under the same domain, sub-domain too I guess?
Domain is not the only indicator of same origin, you could try to iframe yourdomain.com/proxy.google.com as an example. So for all your browser cares that is still a different origin, or else don't iframe it. Calling it .html is meaningless, you can have it .exe and the browser will still attempt to render the dom.

This issue arises when you're trying to merge 2 incompatible frameworks quick and dirty, like for example you need an interface where the main is using ExtJS and the child is Angular... And the only proper/legal/right answer is.

**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage**

You might get lucky and find a hack of some sort but believe me it will only be temporary. PostMessage was written exactly for this purpose, so 2 globals can safely communicate and react to events.

Comment: https://analytics-bypassing-adblockers.netlify.com/proxy/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59456577/changing-the-innerhtml-on-another-page-does-not-work-in-chrome-they-are-in-the/59460477
To illustrate my point, look at this example above, you're visiting a completely different domain, and yet you're still here. So this is still CORS, if you could manipulate another target dom that easily than we would have no chance against phishing attacks. So all your other browsers that "work" are simply wrong and will stop eventually.

Comment: It's already working, with the same code i posted above. The only thing i needed to do was uploading it to a webserver. Thanks for the clear insight, i will look into the info you've send me!

Comment: The thing i was trying to do was just change the text of an id on the parent page by clicking a link on a subpage in the iframe for learning purposes. So it's totaly the same domain, sub domain, even the same folder. Ya get me?